# linker command failed with exit code 1 after update to XCode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I get

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-projectName-AFNetworkActivityLogger
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

while building, after update Xcode to 6.3

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Full log:

```
Ld /Users/radekwilczak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-hkpnskhwpbvwkteungusfkzdjnvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/projectName.app/projectName normal armv7
    cd /Users/radekwilczak/Work/projectName-ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -L/Users/radekwilczak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-hkpnskhwpbvwkteungusfkzdjnvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/radekwilczak/Work/projectName-ios/external/prmediaplayersdk/lib/iphoneos -L/Users/radekwilczak/Work/projectName-ios/external/Upnpx -L/Users/radekwilczak/Work/projectName-ios/external -L/Users/radekwilczak/Work/projectName-ios/external/prmediaplayersdk/lib -L/Users/radekwilczak/Work/projectName-ios/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/radekwilczak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-hkpnskhwpbvwkteungusfkzdjnvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/radekwilczak/Work/projectName-ios/Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastSDK-2.5.2-Release -F/Users/radekwilczak/Work/projectName-ios -filelist /Users/radekwilczak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-hkpnskhwpbvwkteungusfkzdjnvw/Build/Intermediates/projectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/projectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/projectName.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -lPods-projectName-AFNetworkActivityLogger -lPods-projectName-AFNetworking -lPods-projectName-CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout -lPods-projectName-CocoaAsyncSocket -lPods-projectName-CocoaLumberjack -lPods-projectName-JSONModel -lPods-projectName-PureLayout -lPods-projectName-SFHFKeychainUtils -lPods-projectName-SVProgressHUD -lPods-projectName-TTTAttributedLabel -lPods-projectName-TYMActivityIndicatorView -lPods-projectName-TYMProgressBarView -lPods-projectName-google-cast-sdk -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework GoogleCast -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework CoreText -framework MediaAccessibility -framework GoogleCast -framework CoreData -lsqlite3 -lstdc++.6.0.9 -lxml2 -lz -lGoogleAnalyticsServices -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreAudio -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework MessageUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AVFoundation -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Fabric -framework Security -lPRMediaPlayerFramework_v_2_3 -framework Crashlytics -lupnpx -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/radekwilczak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-hkpnskhwpbvwkteungusfkzdjnvw/Build/Intermediates/projectName.build/Debug-iphoneos/projectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/projectName_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/radekwilczak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-hkpnskhwpbvwkteungusfkzdjnvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/projectName.app/projectName

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/radekwilczak/Work/projectName-ios/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: library not found for -lPods-projectName-AFNetworkActivityLogger
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by removing

*libPods.a*

*libPods-CD_GO.a*

and adding

*libPods-CD_GO.a*

one more time (in Frameworks).